# Name of the software used for the given animation

Tags: software, animation

Which software has been used to produce the Wildebeest animated short by Bird Box Studio?  It can be seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JMJXvsCLu6s).

Answer (score 5):

The short film, Wildebeest was rendered in Adobe After Effects and Flash.

This is the quote from an interview by the director Ant Blades.
"The film is animated in Flash and AfterEffects. The main aim was to be funny. The secondary aim was to develop a style I hadn’t tried before."
Source:["Filmmaker Ant Blades, Wildebeest"](http://filmmakermagazine.com/51143-filminute-filmmaker-ant-blades-wildebeest/)

Workflow of Mr Blades is to first sketch in Adobe Flash. As he puts it, it is an easy way to sketch out an "animatic" of an idea. He then renders it with After Effects, I assume he would be using the plug-in Cinema 4D to render the 3D work but that is a guess on my part. A more complete interview and the process in how he creates his works for Bird Box Studio. ["Interview Ant Blades, Bird Box Studio"](http://www.skwigly.co.uk/an-interview-ant-blades-birdbox-studio/)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a mixture of a few 3D renderings composted together with 2D Elements. The heads for example seem to be partially a 3D rendering, also the island they are standing on could be a 3D rendering.

The rest seems to be a 2D [compositing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compositing). This can be achieved with any 3D software suite out there like Cinema 4D, Autodesk 3Ds Max or the open source Blender.
Then a 2D animation/VFX suite is used, the most prominent one being Adobe After Effects but there is also Apple Motion and The Foundry's Nuke.